# VK загрузка фотографии на стену группы

Tags: c#, вконтакте, vkontakte-api, powershell

Доброго времени суток!

Пару дней бьюсь над проблемой публикации картинки в посте на стене группы. Есть standalon приложение, с правами на публикацию записей на стене группы. Обычные сообщения прекрасно уходят, а вот картинку к сообщению так и не получается прикрепить...

Пытаюсь следовать мануалу на сайте контакта, вот что получается:

Получаю адрес загрузки (не совсем понял, зачем отправлять туда картинки). Пробовал отправлять как сами данные картинки, так и просто имя картинки, всегда возвращается результат без ошибки.

```
$site = ($queryAPI -f "photos.getWallUploadServer", ("gid={0}" -f $groupID), $AccessToken);
$wReq = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($site)
$wReq.CookieContainer = $Cookie;
$wReq.ContentType = "multipart/form-data"
$wReq.Method = "POST"
$writer = new-object IO.StreamWriter($wReq.GetRequestStream())
#$writer.Write([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($picPath))
$writer.Write("file.jpg")
$writer.Close()
$stream = new-object IO.StreamReader($wReq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
$str = $stream.ReadToEnd()
$stream.Close();
```

Вот такой вот ответ приходит:

```
upload_url: http://cs624222.vk.com/upload.php?act=do_add&mid=144338474&aid=-14&gid=0&hash=6f0fc65fc3bd214f509dd436a5f18075&rhash=e3cb2d5676aaf772273daa4a5984611a&swfupload=1&api=1&wallphoto=1
album_id:   -14
user_id:    144338474
```

Т.е. понимаю, что вроде как все нормально, следовательно продолжаем далее...
Пытаем загрузить непосредственно картинку по полученному урл.

```
$site = ($queryAPI -f "photos.saveWallPhoto", ("photo={0}&gid={1}" -f $upload_url, $groupID), $AccessToken);
$wReq = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($site)
$wReq.CookieContainer = $Cookie;
$wReq.Method = "POST"
$wReq.ContentType = "multipart/form-data"
$writer = new-object IO.StreamWriter($wReq.GetRequestStream())
$writer.Write([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($picPath))
$writer.Close()
$stream = new-object IO.StreamReader($wReq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
$str = $stream.ReadToEnd()
$stream.Close();
```

После выполнения данного фрагмента кода, вылетает ошибка:

```
 <error_code>118</error_code>
 <error_msg>Invalid server</error_msg>
```

Вот тут у меня, собственно говоря, тупик... Почему неверный сервер, если он сам мне его дал?..

Заранее спасибо за Вашу помощь

Comment: для загрузки фото проще использовать WebClient(upload_url, "POST", imagePath); пример на C# [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474456/196972)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прошу прощения, испытываю некоторые трудности с чтением кода C...
Последовательность действий:

1. Получаем адрес сервера, куда надо отправить картинку. (это сделано)
2. Оправляем по этому адресу саму картинку (не увидел)

   *Запрос должен включать поле **photo**, содержащее файл с изображением (JPG, PNG, BMP или GIF)*
3. В ответ на загрузку сервер даст ответ:`{"server": "1234", "photo": "1234", "hash": "12345abcde"}`
4. Только после этого надо обратиться к методу [`photos.saveWallPhoto`](http://vk.com/dev/photos.saveWallPhoto), на который API вернет id вида `photo_64664646464`, который нужно вложить в вызываемый метод [`wall.post`](http://vk.com/dev/wall.post)

Главное правильно сформировать отправку файла на сервер. Приведу свой код php, который использую для своего проекта:

```
    $ch = curl_init(АДРЕС_ДЛЯ_ЗАГРУЗКИ);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('photo' =>  '@' . realpath("./temp_img.jpg")));

    echo curl_exec($ch);
```

То, что я описал является моей интерпретацией документации, которая приведена [тут](http://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)