# vk.api загрузка изображения на стену пользователя c#

Tags: c#

Здраствуйте. У меня возникла проблема с загрузкой изображения на стену пользователя. Сначало я думал, что я не правельно отправляю POST запрост, но как оказалось проблема в том что я не получаю URI сервера куда надо загрузить изображения. Вот код.

```
WebRequest webRequest =    WebRequest.Create("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?user_id="+userId+"&access_token="+token);
WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream ();
//тут я получаю URI             
stream.Write(arr, 1 , arr.Length);
string jsonR = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arr);
var jso = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonR);
string url = jso["response"]["upload_url"].ToString();
//POST запрос
var  myWebClient = new WebClient();  
byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadFile(url, filePath);
string jsonResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseArray);
var json = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);
string photo = json["response"]["photo"].ToString();
string server = json["response"]["server"].ToString();
string hash = json["response"]["hash"].ToString();
//загрузка изображения
WebRequest.Create("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.saveWallPhoto.xml?aceess_token="+ token+"&server="+server+"&photo="+photo+"&hash="+hash);
xmlDocument.Load (stream);
string photoLoad = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("responce/id").InnerText;
string URI = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post.xml?";
URI +="access_token="+ token;
URI += "&owner_id="+userId;
URI += "&attachments=photo"+userId+"_"+photoLoad;
URI += ",note"+userId+"_"+stext;
URI += "&message="+stext;
WebRequest.Create(URI);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод для загрузки фото и комментария на стену:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
// ...
static string Upload(string userid, string token, string imagePath, string text) {
    var c = new WebClient();
    //
    var u = "https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?user_id=" + userid 
            + "&access_token=" + token;
    var r = c.DownloadString(u);
    var j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(r) as JObject;
    //
    var u2 = j["response"]["upload_url"].ToString();
    var r2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(c.UploadFile(u2, "POST", imagePath));
    var j2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(r2) as JObject;
    //
    var u3 = "https://api.vk.com/method/photos.saveWallPhoto?access_token=" + token
             + "&server=" + j2["server"]
             + "&photo=" + j2["photo"]
             + "&hash=" + j2["hash"];
    var r3 = c.DownloadString(u3);
    var j3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(r3) as JObject;
    // 
    var u4 = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?access_token=" + token
             + "&owner_id" + j3["response"][0]["owner_id"]
             + "&message=" + text
             + "&attachments=" + j3["response"][0]["id"];
    return c.DownloadString(u4);
}
```

Для компиляции кода надо подключить сборку `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` 
А `access_token` должен быть получен для [Photos](https://vk.com/dev/permissions).

Comment: извиняюсь но ет я тут просто скопировал не правильно... у меня запрос отрпавляеца, без пробелов тоисть  :                                         
    "https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?user_id=" +   userId+"&access_token="+token                                                                        И права к Photos, я получаю при авторизации

Comment: "токен для Photos, и как єво получить?" -- также как вы получили `access_token`, только когда обращаетесь к `https://oauth.vk.com/authorize` в значение scope надо указать/добавить 4.

Comment: var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
      clientId: "",  
      scope: "wall,photos,notes,pages", 
      authorizeUrl: new System.Uri ("https://oauth.vk.com/authorize"),
      redirectUrl: new System.Uri ("https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html"));         При авторизации все получаю, постить просто на стену пользователя текст постит, но при отправке запроса почемуто я не получаю ответ, или мб я не правельно єво получаю... но сам запрос проверял по буковке и правельно

Comment: var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var httpRequest = httpClient.GetStringAsync ("https://api.vk.com /method/photos.getWallUploadServer?user_id="+ userId + "&access_token=" + token);
     var result = httpRequest.Result;
     var js2 = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
     string url = js2["response"]["upload_url"].ToString();                             Я правильно извлекаю результат?

Comment: Спасибо URL уже получаю но почемуто уже у меня не записует атрибути уже загруженого пост запросом фото. var  myWebClient = new WebClient();  
byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadFile(url, filePath);
string jsonResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseArray);
var json = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);
string photo = json["response"]["photo"].ToString();
string server = json["response"]["server"].ToString();
string hash = json["response"]["hash"].ToString();    На парсинге вилетает

Comment: в ответ добавил код для загрузки фото и комментария на стену.

Comment: огромное спасибо, никогда не использовал WebClient... и никогда не делал POST Запрос((( радует то, что бил близок ))