# API twitter Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, twitter-api

Как сделать простой GET запрос к API twitter на JavaScript (к примеру GET statuses/user_timeline ) Какие параметры в него нужно передавать и сколько?

Comment: примерно так `var r = new XMLHttpRequest(); r.open("GET", "тут адрес функции апи твиттера", true); r.send();` а какие параметры передавать - указано в документации твиттера.

Comment: @Stack ну да указаны.Ну а когда мы создаем приложение для API, мы после получаем Consumer Key Consumer Secret Access Token Access Token Secret. Нужно ли их передавать в параметрах?

Comment: @Stack например метод GET statuses/user_timeline требует аутентификации, а разве access_token не подтверждает ее (аутентификацию), если его передавать в запросе?

Comment: с твиттер апи не работал. но например для vk апи надо access_token передавать в запросе. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474456/196972)