# Пустой photo при upload фотографии через VK Api

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, http, вконтакте, post

Пытаюсь отправить POST запрос для того чтобы сохранить фотографию товара в ВК. фото заливается в три этапа

1. получаю ссылку куда отправлять запрос
2. отправляю методом POST фотографию и получаю её адрес
3. вставляю её в группу
   Проблема на втором шаге, я не получаю адреса фотографии... то что фотографию отправляется на сайт точно, проверял на сайте, что возвращает POST запрос.

получил комментарий от поддержки, что файл должен называться в форме file... сделал, но не помогло это заголовок, отправляемый моей программой

HEADERS:

```
X-Request-Id: ec2d0f88-5cd5-41e5-af95-6699793a64d0
Total-Route-Time: 0
Connect-Time: 3004
Via: 1.1 vegur
Connection: close
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary====1454361659830===
Host: requestb.in
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_66
Content-Length: 132951
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
RAW BODY
--===1454361659830===
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="111.jpg"
```

дальше пошёл файл

но я с таким POST запросом не получаю photos

SERVER REPLIED:

```javascript
{  
    "server" : 629110,
    "photo" : "[]",
    "hash" : "4d26842822504db5c92d94f77ad38da5"
}
```

а это заголовки питоновского скрипта, который работает

HEADERS:

```
X-Request-Id: 31b332f7-45c2-4e34-a6ae-fa03a8fa441f
Total-Route-Time: 0
Connect-Time: 1
Via: 1.1 vegur
User-Agent: python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/2.7.10 Linux/4.2.0-25-generic
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=2f9acf9099c944168d0de3389086cb5c
Connection: close
Content-Length: 132977
Host: requestb.in
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
RAW BODY
--2f9acf9099c944168d0de3389086cb5c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="111.jpg"
```

я не одинок в этой проблеме, есть вымученные решения для python, php. Но хочется на Java разобраться как сделать. Что можно сделать?

UPD
ОТВЕТ ПОЛУЧИЛ!

Comment: _"upload фотографии через VK Api"_ -- пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474456/196972)

Comment: сделайте не приватный RequestBin - сейчас при переходе по ссылке,  всем кроме вас отображается "не найдено"

Comment: к сожалению http://requestb.in потёр уже всё :(

Comment: Stack спасибо за пример... я уже понял, что Java язык для тех кто любит много писать :) я не стал выкладывать свой проект потому что простыня. Наверно зря. вот он https://yadi.sk/d/470p4ACkoBGff
К сожалению пример на C# мне не помог как и на php и python

Comment: Для начала сделайте что поддержка посоветовала и обновите вопрос

Comment: @NikolayBelyaev , есть разница между Вашим и питоновским скриптом: `form-data` должна вести наименования полей, начиная с `file1`, а не просто `file`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: мне 22 часа надо ещё ждать, чтобы сделать это

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробовал вариант apache httpclient. не получилось. подошёл HttpClientBuilder

```
private static String postit3(String uploadUrl, String imagepath) throws Exception {
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = builder.build();

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uploadUrl);

MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entityBuilder.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File(imagepath)));
// entityBuilder.addPart("fileb", new FileBody(fileb));
final HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);


String inputLine;
StringBuffer response2 = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response2.append(inputLine);
}
reader.close();

// print result
System.out.println(response2.toString());
return response.toString();
}
```

Comment: Супер! Обдолбился уже и в коде и в Интернете, поддержка ВК неделю молчит, а этот вариант сработал. Я безуспешно пробовал путь с MultipartEntityBuilder, который работает при отправке файла на тестовые сервера, но не нравится серверу ВК. Спасибо за смену парадигмы.